# Solution of $ 1+ 5 * 2^m =n^2$ Equation and some other question from this equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find all integer Solutions of $ 1+ 5 * 2^m =n^2$ Equation . From this eqn I have to answer the following answer .

1. I have to find an expression for $ n^2-1 $
2. Are $ (n+1) $ and $ (n-1) $ both even or both odd or is one even and the other odd ?
3. Let $ a = \frac{n-1}{2} $ . I have to find an expression for $ a(a+1) $ .
4. If a is odd , is $ (a+1) $ even or odd ?
5. From parts 3 and 4 , is it possible for $ a(a+1) =1 $ or $ a=1 $ ?
6. I have to find the pnly possible values a can take and then have to find what m and n should be ?

   I want to have the solution of the above equation . Then I will answer the above question .

Comment: This looks like six questions...

Comment: Please ask these 7 questions one at a time with the usual routine, perspective, and your thoughts. It really helps. 7 questions is fine provided they come with the perspective, and the "what you have tried" part. You will probably get 7 answers. The obligatory [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: All these questions are parts of a sinlge question and can be answered from the equation .

Comment: Given that, what are your thoughts?  Have you already solved any of these pieces?

Comment: This resembles a test more than homework.

Comment: I do not understand your comment . @WillJagy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am considering the case $m\ge 2$

Observe that $5\cdot2^m=n^2-1$ is even and so are $n\pm1$

and $(n-1,n+1)=(n-1,n+1-(n-1))=(n+1,2)=2$

alternatively, if integer $d>0$ divides both $n+1,n-1, d$ will divide $n+1-(n-1)=2$

$\implies (n-1,n+1)|2\implies (n-1,n+1)=2$ as $n\pm1$  are even

So, we have
$$5\cdot2^{m-2}=\frac{n+1}2\cdot \frac{n-1}2$$ with  $\left(\frac{n+1}2,\frac{n-1}2\right)=1$

So, either $\displaystyle\frac{n+1}2=5; \frac{n-1}2=2^{m-2}$

or $\displaystyle\frac{n-1}2=5; \frac{n+1}2=2^{m-2}$

or $\displaystyle\frac{n-1}2=5\cdot2^{m-2} ;\frac{n+1}2=1$

or $\displaystyle\frac{n+1}2=5\cdot2^{m-2} ;\frac{n-1}2=1$

Comment: No need to go berzerk with algebra here :). Since 6 is not a solution, $n=2k+1\implies 5*2^{m-2}=k(k+1)$. Since $(k,k+1)=1$, we have $k=4$or $5$, and just $4$ works.

Comment: @chubakueno, I have left it to the user to validate